# How to change date format in datepicker using JqueryUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I have datepicker, it does display date, but i want use correct date format according my timezone(in SA).

```
 <!---DatePicker----> 
 <div class = "container">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
    </div>
  </div><br>

 // date functionality
    $(function() {
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
      autoClose:true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

    });
  });
```

Comment: please share yout date format

Comment: I did, check the above Jquery code and HTML

Comment: please check my answer as per your required format

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[id$=tbDate]').datepicker({  
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' //add your format here
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Change Date Format Example</title>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Set focus on the box to select a date. (shows default format)</p>
    <div>
        Date: <input type="text" id="tbDate" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please check link for more info
[Link](//www.encodedna.com/jquery/ui-datepicker-widget-change-date-format.htm)